# Lua: Is there a way to identify non-defined functions before runtime?

Tags: lua, compilation, static-analysis, preprocessor

Several times I am faced with Lua runtime errors due to calls to functions that don't exist (sometimes due to typos in their names, sometimes due restructuring code,..).

So, I was wondering if there a way for me to identify those calls to non-defined functions before runtime?

I found some scripts to identify non-defined Global variables, but they appear to work only in one file (my projects have dozens of lua files).

**UPDATE: Here is a example:**

**b.lua**

```
local b = {}

b.myTest = function()
end

return b
```

**main.lua**

```
local function myFunc()
end
local myModule = require("b")


myFunc() -- works
myfunc() -- error

myModule.myTest() -- works
myModule.mytext() -- error
```

So, I would like a way to run some kind of script/preprocessor to identify those 2 errors before having to actually run the code (which would give a runtime error)

**UPDATE 2**

@hjpotter92 mentioned ZeroBrane IDE and I took a look on it. It relies on luacheck do to live static analysis, so I installed the SublimeLinter-luacheck on my Sublime and I now can detect undefined functions on the same file. Unfortunately, it does not detect those defined on tables or outside modules.

[image]

Comment: So, for example, in one of your files you have defined a function named `func1()`, but in another file you have referred that function as `func2()`, and you are looking for some tool for automatic search for this sort of typos?

Comment: I added a code example of what I mean by a function in another file.

Comment: Only functions? What about misspelled variable names and table fields?

Comment: You can use `luac` to compile your file to byte-code without executing anything.  This will catch any syntax error.  Semantic errors like misspelled function or variable names cannot be caught (same holds for any other interpreted language, e.g. Python).  For the latter you need unit tests, which is what they are there for.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, I am mainly interested in functions and I think those would easier to spot than any variable (a variable == nil should be acceptable in several scenarios, but a call to a nil function should not).

Comment: @ Henri Menke, neither luac not unit tests would catch those errors.

Comment: use an IDE, such as zerobrain etc.

Comment: @hjpotter92, zerobrain does something but not the check against several files. If I am not mistaken, it relies on luacheck which is a very good tool but it does not catch undefined functions defined under tables / outside files.

Comment: @rsc If your unit tests do not catch such errors, it means your code is not covered by the tests, which is bad.

Comment: @HenriMenke, unit tests is used for testing functions: you gave a set of inputs and checks if the results are what you would expect. It does not catch typos on a function name call inside your code.

Comment: @rsc No, unit tests *will* catch this error if every line of your program is covered.  Of course, if your unit tests only cover `b.lua` but not `main.lua` you won't find those errors.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I think you may be using a non-standard definition of unit test.  Unit testing is used to test specific modules of your project (most commonly functions). You create a test case that would call a specific module/function and assert the result. Saying "if every line of your program is covered" does not make sense on Unit testing. But I don't want to turn this comment area in a Unit Testing discussion. This will be my last reply about the subject. This video gives a very good overview of the most used methods: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgfww8tLM0A (Unit test on time 1m30s)

Comment: @rsc Whatever man.  The fact is that you cannot detect this error unless you run that specific line of code, period.

Comment: @HenriMenke, sorry but you are wrong again. As hjpotter92 pointed, luacheck can detect undefined functions call without running the code. The only downside is that it only works inside the same file.

Comment: @hjpotter92, your suggestion for luacheck (used by ZeroBraine) was the best one so far. Do u mind answering so I can upvote and mark as the solution?